# Error occur while adding controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

I am developing MVC 3 application and using razor syntax.(EF 4.0)

I am trying to add controller to my App. but whenever I try to add the controller I get the following error.

I am trying to add controller in test copy as well sourcesafe copy...

[image]

And the error is....

[image]

When I try add the controller in SourceSafe copy of the same application , below error comes...

[image]

How to solve it ?

Comment: Could it be that you dont have SourceSafe set to AutoCheckOut files. SourceSafe edits the properties of the files so that you cannot edit them without checking out the file first

Comment: But If I dont use sourcesafe copy still issue come...

Answer (score 0):

Look into this article, your solution is most likely there.

**Edit**

Please take a look into this article dealing with specifically "Unsopported context type" during controller scaffolding: [Unsupported context type in controller wizard.](http://forums.asp.net/t/1675477.aspx)
Hope you can get ideas and solution from there...

Hope this helps

Comment: It shows me the error 'Unsupported context Type', the link you have given might work at their solution but I think its some other issue.